# jQuery - $(this) + Selector - .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to do a nested `.each()` so that I only target descendants of the current iteration of the parent.

For example:

```
$('.row-day').each(function() {
    let dayFlag = false; 

    $(this)('.row-timeslot').each(function() {

    });
});
```

Except I know the above won't work, but should do for describing what I'd like to do. There will be many children for `.row-timeslot` so I need to use a `.each`. I've read maybe a `.find()` but I don't know if that will iterate over all of the children. Thanks for any help!

Comment: `$('.row-timelot', this)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this)('.row-timeslot')` is invalid JS construct.

In `.row-timeslot` is a child of `.row-day`, you're looking for `.find()`.

```
$('.row-day').each(function() {
    let dayFlag = false; 

    // here $(this) contains one of .row-days

    $(this).find('.row-timeslot').each(function() {
        // here $(this) contains one of .row-timeslots
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh, awesome, I didn't know that `.each()` could chain to `.find()`. Thanks!